# Loading Google Map using geocode

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to Load a google map using geocoding and Jquery but I cant seem to find a good tutorial based on this. I will appreciate if any of you can direct me to some good resrouces or give a speudo code of how I can implement this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/